# html Limiting of lettering in span

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to limit the amount of the letters using CSS that a tag can will show like the titles on YouTube. I was looking at the styles and can't see how they did it or if they used JS. thanks

Comment: a piece of your code and try would help

Comment: I know how to do this with Php very easily... are you able to use that?

Comment: css ? : overflow, text-overflow + white-space & display eventually

Comment: What you need is a fixed width and`overflow : hidden`

Answer (score 2):

You can truncate text and add an ellipsis like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

p {
    width: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text</p>

</body>
</html>
```